# AngularJS filter distance with input text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

**Task**
To omit ng-repeat values greater than specified distance(eg:3kms).

I use [Angular Filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) and using omit in that.

The below code works fine. It removes ng-repeat values with distance greater than 3 kms.

```
|omit:'distance > 3'
```

I tried to achieve the same with a button

```
<p><button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="getDistance = 3">Show less than 3kms</button></p>

  |omit:'distance > getDistance'
```

I will try my best to create a jsFiddle, if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation given for Angular filter and the description, if you had some collection and wanted to filter based on `distance` on each element:

```
<p><button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="getDistance = 3">Show less than 3kms</button></p>

<span ng-repeat="obj in collection | omit: distance > getDistance">
    {{ obj.someValue }}
</span>
```

Then make `getDistance` a field on your `$scope` and `distance` a field on each object in `collection`.

I've not used this but I would think your solution would be similar to this.